# YOLO: how to deal with object partially in training image

Tags: machine-learning, training, yolo

I am trying to train a YOLO (v3) network on a set of images, but I am faced with a problem when preparing the training set.

Sometimes, an image contains my object of interest, but only half of the object is visible in the image (e.g. half a cat, with the rest out of frame). How do I deal with that?

Should I:

- Still including the bounding box of the partial object in the training set?
- Only include bounding boxes for objects which are fully in the frame?
- Only include bounding boxes of objects whose "fractional area in frame" is above a certain threshold? (e.g. objects that are `90%` in frame)

And if I need to include partial objects, should I give the bounding box containing the part of the object visible in the frame? Or should I give the `actual` bounding box (which would thus go over the edges of the images) of the "true", full object (which I actually have access to)?